# Hide UiApplication Icon on a BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, hide, invisible, uiapplication, application-icon

I am creating a tracking application. Once configured, the application should always run in the background, without the knowledge of user.

There is option to hide the application icon manually by selecting the app and pressing the BlackBerry icon and clicking hide. Is it possible to do this by EventInjector? Or any other method?

Comment: Is this a corporate requirement ?

Comment: What platform are you using? UIApplication is an iOS class.

Comment: @Maz it's a BlackBerry class too http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html

Comment: in your BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml enable (Mark) the Auto Run on startup and donot display the application icon in homescreen.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the Project
2. Click on Application tab
3. Select the 'System Module' checkbox.

This can be done in the native JDE or Eclipse. Otherwise, try playing around with the JAD file.